# Странное значение указателей на поля-данные класса

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток!

Указатель на поля-данные класса  равен числу(оно же количество байт), на которое нужно сместиться от начала объекта, чтобы начать читать то поле класса, на которое указывает указатель. Собственно в этих рамках я и писал код ниже:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class someClass{
    public:
    someClass(){
        cout << "HALO" << endl;
    }
    int a;
    char b;
    double c;
};

int main(){
    int someClass::*p1 = &someClass::a;
    double someClass::*p2 = &someClass::c;
    cout << p1 << " " << p2 << endl;
    someClass* p = new someClass;
    p->*p1 = 10;
    p->*p2 = 20;
    cout << p1 << " " << p2 << endl;
    delete p;
}
```

Почему указатели имеют значение равное 1?

Comment: Указатели на члены класса - это не указатели, а более сложные сущности.

Answer (score 2):

Эти указатели не "имеют значение равное 1". Это вы их просто выводите как булевские значения `true`, которые по умолчанию выводятся как `1`.

В стандартной библиотеке нет оператора `<<` для вывода указателей на члены класса. Поэтому ваше

```
cout << p1 << " " << p2 << endl;
```

использует "самый подходящий" оператор `<<` из имеющихся в наличии - оператор для вывода `bool`. Результаты его работы вы и видите. Если указатель не null, выведется `1`, а если null, то выведется `0`.

Comment: Если я просто сделаю объявление указателя, то значение будет так же 1, не 0. Так что непонятно, как работает это приведение типов.

Comment: @Semerkin Что значит "просто объявление указателя"?

Comment: int someclass::* p;

Comment: @Semerkin: Ну так вы неинициализированный указатель печатаете. Содержащийся в нем мусор не является null указателем - печатается `1`. Что вы хотели увидеть, печатая неинициализированный указатель - не ясно.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере вам нужно выводить следующим образом

```
someClass* p = new someClass;
p->*p1 = 10;
p->*p2 = 20;
cout << p ->*p1 << " " << p->*p2 << endl;
```

хотя непонятно зачем тут понадобились вам указатели на член

Comment: Простите, на что указатель?